# Android app process is destroyed when overlay app like messenger is in the foreground

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an android app which has processes, let's say Process1 and Process1:A

From Process1, when a particular call is made Process1:A is spawned. When Process1:A is running, it calls another backend service and waits for a response. While it is waiting for the response, if I open an app with overlay, say DU Recorder app and start the recording from the overlay menu, the Process1:A gets killed abruptly without leaving any traces of the logs regarding why it died. Tried looking into the onPause and onStop methods from activity lifecycle, they're never called.

It doesn't seem like memory issue to me. Phone I'm testing on has almost 4GB of ram unused.

Tried to test the app by killing the process from android studio while it is running, and it respawns automatically resuming the operation, but when it comes to the overlay app, it just dies abruptly and never respawns unless I restart the app manually.

Similar behavior is observed when class 0 flash message is shown while the Process1:A is waiting for a response.

Is this something someone has already experienced or has idea about? I'd also like to know what is the behavior of the app when there's an overlay in terms of activity lifecycle.

Update: This seems to happen only with Android 9 and doesn't cause any problems with Android 8 and below devices. I looked at the changelog/release notes for android 9 to see if there was any change in the way notifications/overlay works, but didn't find anything specific.

Comment: Wow, surprisingly I am the only one facing this problem here and no one seems to have any clue whatsoever :(